# How to make two different functions from this php class?

Tags: php, gd

I am having a classes which have function to make random text and captcha image based on that random text all in one function. What I want is to make them apart. I mean I want to have different function which will make random text, I would save it in cookie, and then the captcha making function should run. I want to have function like this:

```
$string = make_text(); //random text

setcookie($string); // will write the cookie

make_captcha($string);
```

following is the class from where we can make it:

```
class KCAPTCHA{

// generates keystring and image
function KCAPTCHA(){

    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/kcaptcha_config.php');
    $fonts=array();
    $fontsdir_absolute=dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$fontsdir;
    if ($handle = opendir($fontsdir_absolute)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if (preg_match('/\.png$/i', $file)) {
                $fonts[]=$fontsdir_absolute.'/'.$file;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }   

    $alphabet_length=strlen($alphabet);

    do{
        // generating random keystring
        while(true){
            $this->keystring='';
            for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
                $this->keystring.=$allowed_symbols{mt_rand(0,strlen($allowed_symbols)-1)};
            }
            if(!preg_match('/cp|cb|ck|c6|c9|rn|rm|mm|co|do|cl|db|qp|qb|dp|ww/', $this->keystring)) break;
        }

        $font_file=$fonts[mt_rand(0, count($fonts)-1)];
        $font=imagecreatefrompng($font_file);
        imagealphablending($font, true);

        $fontfile_width=imagesx($font);
        $fontfile_height=imagesy($font)-1;

        $font_metrics=array();
        $symbol=0;
        $reading_symbol=false;

        // loading font
        for($i=0;$i<$fontfile_width && $symbol<$alphabet_length;$i++){
            $transparent = (imagecolorat($font, $i, 0) >> 24) == 127;

            if(!$reading_symbol && !$transparent){
                $font_metrics[$alphabet{$symbol}]=array('start'=>$i);
                $reading_symbol=true;
                continue;
            }

            if($reading_symbol && $transparent){
                $font_metrics[$alphabet{$symbol}]['end']=$i;
                $reading_symbol=false;
                $symbol++;
                continue;
            }
        }

        $img=imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagealphablending($img, true);
        $white=imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
        $black=imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);

        imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, $width-1, $height-1, $white);

        // draw text
        $x=1;
        $odd=mt_rand(0,1);
        if($odd==0) $odd=-1;
        for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
            $m=$font_metrics[$this->keystring{$i}];

            $y=(($i%2)*$fluctuation_amplitude - $fluctuation_amplitude/2)*$odd
                + mt_rand(-round($fluctuation_amplitude/3), round($fluctuation_amplitude/3))
                + ($height-$fontfile_height)/2;

            if($no_spaces){
                $shift=0;
                if($i>0){
                    $shift=10000;
                    for($sy=3;$sy<$fontfile_height-10;$sy+=1){
                        for($sx=$m['start']-1;$sx<$m['end'];$sx+=1){
                            $rgb=imagecolorat($font, $sx, $sy);
                            $opacity=$rgb>>24;
                            if($opacity<127){
                                $left=$sx-$m['start']+$x;
                                $py=$sy+$y;
                                if($py>$height) break;
                                for($px=min($left,$width-1);$px>$left-200 && $px>=0;$px-=1){
                                    $color=imagecolorat($img, $px, $py) & 0xff;
                                    if($color+$opacity<170){ // 170 - threshold
                                        if($shift>$left-$px){
                                            $shift=$left-$px;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if($shift==10000){
                        $shift=mt_rand(4,6);
                    }

                }
            }else{
                $shift=1;
            }
            imagecopy($img, $font, $x-$shift, $y, $m['start'], 1, $m['end']-$m['start'], $fontfile_height);
            $x+=$m['end']-$m['start']-$shift;
        }
    }while($x>=$width-10); // while not fit in canvas

    //noise
    $white=imagecolorallocate($font, 255, 255, 255);
    $black=imagecolorallocate($font, 0, 0, 0);
    for($i=0;$i<(($height-30)*$x)*$white_noise_density;$i++){
        imagesetpixel($img, mt_rand(0, $x-1), mt_rand(10, $height-15), $white);
    }
    for($i=0;$i<(($height-30)*$x)*$black_noise_density;$i++){
        imagesetpixel($img, mt_rand(0, $x-1), mt_rand(10, $height-15), $black);
    }


    $center=$x/2;

    // credits. To remove, see configuration file
    $img2=imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height+($show_credits?12:0));
    $foreground=imagecolorallocate($img2, $foreground_color[0], $foreground_color[1], $foreground_color[2]);
    $background=imagecolorallocate($img2, $background_color[0], $background_color[1], $background_color[2]);
    imagefilledrectangle($img2, 0, 0, $width-1, $height-1, $background);        
    imagefilledrectangle($img2, 0, $height, $width-1, $height+12, $foreground);
    $credits=empty($credits)?$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']:$credits;
    imagestring($img2, 2, $width/2-imagefontwidth(2)*strlen($credits)/2, $height-2, $credits, $background);

    // periods
    $rand1=mt_rand(750000,1200000)/10000000;
    $rand2=mt_rand(750000,1200000)/10000000;
    $rand3=mt_rand(750000,1200000)/10000000;
    $rand4=mt_rand(750000,1200000)/10000000;
    // phases
    $rand5=mt_rand(0,31415926)/10000000;
    $rand6=mt_rand(0,31415926)/10000000;
    $rand7=mt_rand(0,31415926)/10000000;
    $rand8=mt_rand(0,31415926)/10000000;
    // amplitudes
    $rand9=mt_rand(330,420)/110;
    $rand10=mt_rand(330,450)/100;

    //wave distortion

    for($x=0;$x<$width;$x++){
        for($y=0;$y<$height;$y++){
            $sx=$x+(sin($x*$rand1+$rand5)+sin($y*$rand3+$rand6))*$rand9-$width/2+$center+1;
            $sy=$y+(sin($x*$rand2+$rand7)+sin($y*$rand4+$rand8))*$rand10;

            if($sx<0 || $sy<0 || $sx>=$width-1 || $sy>=$height-1){
                continue;
            }else{
                $color=imagecolorat($img, $sx, $sy) & 0xFF;
                $color_x=imagecolorat($img, $sx+1, $sy) & 0xFF;
                $color_y=imagecolorat($img, $sx, $sy+1) & 0xFF;
                $color_xy=imagecolorat($img, $sx+1, $sy+1) & 0xFF;
            }

            if($color==255 && $color_x==255 && $color_y==255 && $color_xy==255){
                continue;
            }else if($color==0 && $color_x==0 && $color_y==0 && $color_xy==0){
                $newred=$foreground_color[0];
                $newgreen=$foreground_color[1];
                $newblue=$foreground_color[2];
            }else{
                $frsx=$sx-floor($sx);
                $frsy=$sy-floor($sy);
                $frsx1=1-$frsx;
                $frsy1=1-$frsy;

                $newcolor=(
                    $color*$frsx1*$frsy1+
                    $color_x*$frsx*$frsy1+
                    $color_y*$frsx1*$frsy+
                    $color_xy*$frsx*$frsy);

                if($newcolor>255) $newcolor=255;
                $newcolor=$newcolor/255;
                $newcolor0=1-$newcolor;

                $newred=$newcolor0*$foreground_color[0]+$newcolor*$background_color[0];
                $newgreen=$newcolor0*$foreground_color[1]+$newcolor*$background_color[1];
                $newblue=$newcolor0*$foreground_color[2]+$newcolor*$background_color[2];
            }

            imagesetpixel($img2, $x, $y, imagecolorallocate($img2, $newred, $newgreen, $newblue));
        }
    }

    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); 
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE); 
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    if(function_exists("imagejpeg")){
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        imagejpeg($img2, null, $jpeg_quality);
    }else if(function_exists("imagegif")){
        header("Content-Type: image/gif");
        imagegif($img2);
    }else if(function_exists("imagepng")){
        header("Content-Type: image/x-png");
        imagepng($img2);
    }
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Don't send the solution to the client side. That defeats the whole purpose of a captcha.

Comment: I was about to say you could encrypt it - however on reflection that doesn't solve anything (replay attacks, mitm) so I'll up-vote bongi instead.

Comment: You could also use ReCAPTCHA instead of building your own CAPTCHA implementation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's bad idea to store captcha in cookies because right captcha can be easily read from cookies by bot. Better use session or some storage instead.

Second, there are some variables initialized in kcaptcha_config.php file, you need to move required variables initialization to your functions

Get text function:

```
function make_text()
{
    // generating random keystring
    while(true){
        $keystring='';
        for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
            $keystring.=$allowed_symbols{mt_rand(0,strlen($allowed_symbols)-1)};
        }
        if(!preg_match('/cp|cb|ck|c6|c9|rn|rm|mm|co|do|cl|db|qp|qb|dp|ww/', $keystring)) break;
    }

    return $keystring;
}
```

$length and $allowed_symbols are defined in kcaptcha_config.php

I did not check all the variables in next function, but i'm sure there will be a lot of errors.

```
function make_captcha($keystring){

  $fonts=array();
  $fontsdir_absolute=dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$fontsdir;
  if ($handle = opendir($fontsdir_absolute)) {
      while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          if (preg_match('/\.png$/i', $file)) {
              $fonts[]=$fontsdir_absolute.'/'.$file;
          }
      }
      closedir($handle);
  }

  $alphabet_length=strlen($alphabet);

  do{

      $font_file=$fonts[mt_rand(0, count($fonts)-1)];
      $font=imagecreatefrompng($font_file);
      imagealphablending($font, true);

      $fontfile_width=imagesx($font);
      $fontfile_height=imagesy($font)-1;

      $font_metrics=array();
      $symbol=0;
      $reading_symbol=false;

      // loading font
      for($i=0;$i<$fontfile_width && $symbol<$alphabet_length;$i++){
          $transparent = (imagecolorat($font, $i, 0) >> 24) == 127;

          if(!$reading_symbol && !$transparent){
              $font_metrics[$alphabet{$symbol}]=array('start'=>$i);
              $reading_symbol=true;
              continue;
          }

          if($reading_symbol && $transparent){
              $font_metrics[$alphabet{$symbol}]['end']=$i;
              $reading_symbol=false;
              $symbol++;
              continue;
          }
      }

      $img=imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagealphablending($img, true);
      $white=imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
      $black=imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);

      imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, $width-1, $height-1, $white);

      // draw text
      $x=1;
      $odd=mt_rand(0,1);
      if($odd==0) $odd=-1;
      for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
          $m=$font_metrics[$keystring{$i}];

          $y=(($i%2)*$fluctuation_amplitude - $fluctuation_amplitude/2)*$odd
              + mt_rand(-round($fluctuation_amplitude/3), round($fluctuation_amplitude/3))
              + ($height-$fontfile_height)/2;

          if($no_spaces){
              $shift=0;
              if($i>0){
                  $shift=10000;
                  for($sy=3;$sy<$fontfile_height-10;$sy+=1){
                      for($sx=$m['start']-1;$sx<$m['end'];$sx+=1){
                          $rgb=imagecolorat($font, $sx, $sy);
                          $opacity=$rgb>>24;
                          if($opacity<127){
                              $left=$sx-$m['start']+$x;
                              $py=$sy+$y;
                              if($py>$height) break;
                              for($px=min($left,$width-1);$px>$left-200 && $px>=0;$px-=1){
                                  $color=imagecolorat($img, $px, $py) & 0xff;
                                  if($color+$opacity<170){ // 170 - threshold
                                      if($shift>$left-$px){
                                          $shift=$left-$px;
                                      }
                                      break;
                                  }
                              }
                              break;
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  if($shift==10000){
                      $shift=mt_rand(4,6);
                  }

              }
          }else{
              $shift=1;
          }
          imagecopy($img, $font, $x-$shift, $y, $m['start'], 1, $m['end']-$m['start'], $fontfile_height);
          $x+=$m['end']-$m['start']-$shift;
      }
  }while($x>=$width-10); // while not fit in canvas

  //noise
  $white=imagecolorallocate($font, 255, 255, 255);
  $black=imagecolorallocate($font, 0, 0, 0);
  for($i=0;$i<(($height-30)*$x)*$white_noise_density;$i++){
      imagesetpixel($img, mt_rand(0, $x-1), mt_rand(10, $height-15), $white);
  }
  for($i=0;$i<(($height-30)*$x)*$black_noise_density;$i++){
      imagesetpixel($img, mt_rand(0, $x-1), mt_rand(10, $height-15), $black);
  }


  $center=$x/2;

  // credits. To remove, see configuration file
  $img2=imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height+($show_credits?12:0));
  $foreground=imagecolorallocate($img2, $foreground_color[0], $foreground_color[1], $foreground_color[2]);
  $background=imagecolorallocate($img2, $background_color[0], $background_color[1], $background_color[2]);
  imagefilledrectangle($img2, 0, 0, $width-1, $height-1, $background);
  imagefilledrectangle($img2, 0, $height, $width-1, $height+12, $foreground);
  $credits=empty($credits)?$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']:$credits;
  imagestring($img2, 2, $width/2-imagefontwidth(2)*strlen($credits)/2, $height-2, $credits, $background);

  // periods
  $rand1=mt_rand(750000,1200000)/10000000;
  $rand2=mt_rand(750000,1200000)/10000000;
  $rand3=mt_rand(750000,1200000)/10000000;
  $rand4=mt_rand(750000,1200000)/10000000;
  // phases
  $rand5=mt_rand(0,31415926)/10000000;
  $rand6=mt_rand(0,31415926)/10000000;
  $rand7=mt_rand(0,31415926)/10000000;
  $rand8=mt_rand(0,31415926)/10000000;
  // amplitudes
  $rand9=mt_rand(330,420)/110;
  $rand10=mt_rand(330,450)/100;

  //wave distortion

  for($x=0;$x<$width;$x++){
      for($y=0;$y<$height;$y++){
          $sx=$x+(sin($x*$rand1+$rand5)+sin($y*$rand3+$rand6))*$rand9-$width/2+$center+1;
          $sy=$y+(sin($x*$rand2+$rand7)+sin($y*$rand4+$rand8))*$rand10;

          if($sx<0 || $sy<0 || $sx>=$width-1 || $sy>=$height-1){
              continue;
          }else{
              $color=imagecolorat($img, $sx, $sy) & 0xFF;
              $color_x=imagecolorat($img, $sx+1, $sy) & 0xFF;
              $color_y=imagecolorat($img, $sx, $sy+1) & 0xFF;
              $color_xy=imagecolorat($img, $sx+1, $sy+1) & 0xFF;
          }

          if($color==255 && $color_x==255 && $color_y==255 && $color_xy==255){
              continue;
          }else if($color==0 && $color_x==0 && $color_y==0 && $color_xy==0){
              $newred=$foreground_color[0];
              $newgreen=$foreground_color[1];
              $newblue=$foreground_color[2];
          }else{
              $frsx=$sx-floor($sx);
              $frsy=$sy-floor($sy);
              $frsx1=1-$frsx;
              $frsy1=1-$frsy;

              $newcolor=(
                  $color*$frsx1*$frsy1+
                  $color_x*$frsx*$frsy1+
                  $color_y*$frsx1*$frsy+
                  $color_xy*$frsx*$frsy);

              if($newcolor>255) $newcolor=255;
              $newcolor=$newcolor/255;
              $newcolor0=1-$newcolor;

              $newred=$newcolor0*$foreground_color[0]+$newcolor*$background_color[0];
              $newgreen=$newcolor0*$foreground_color[1]+$newcolor*$background_color[1];
              $newblue=$newcolor0*$foreground_color[2]+$newcolor*$background_color[2];
          }

          imagesetpixel($img2, $x, $y, imagecolorallocate($img2, $newred, $newgreen, $newblue));
      }
  }

  header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
  header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
  header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  if(function_exists("imagejpeg")){
      header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
      imagejpeg($img2, null, $jpeg_quality);
  }else if(function_exists("imagegif")){
      header("Content-Type: image/gif");
      imagegif($img2);
  }else if(function_exists("imagepng")){
      header("Content-Type: image/x-png");
      imagepng($img2);
  }
}
```

Hope i helped you.

Comment: Yes I know that. But i will encrypt it with salt it would be hard to do it. I will check the function and would reply you back. Thank You

Comment: strangely both function dont work. they just work when working as one function

Comment: as i said, sone variables are been initialized in kcaptcha_config.php, you need to copy theese initializatiobs from this file to your functions